# Remove gap between two different (large) shapefiles

Tags: qgis, shapefile, grass-gis

I'm trying to run a somewhat automated process on two shapefiles to fill gaps in between a water and country boundary. I want to bring the Country boundary to meet the more detailed water polygon. Would this be possible in QGIS or GRASS? so far its seems this has been done but within a single shapefile?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE.  As a new user, please take the [Tour](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour).  We use a "Focused Question/Best Answer" model here, so the methods necessary for QGIS and GRASS would constitute two different questions. Please **edit** the question to focus on one environment.  It's also best to not ask Boolean questions, especially those in the form "Is it possible", since getting a "Yes" answer isn't actually going to help much.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @Vince. QGIS only answer here:

1. Open the attribute table and choose 'Field filter' and select the water features.
2. Ctrl-click the layer in TOC and 'Duplicate'. In the duplicate (may save as separate file) you do the same to select the water features again and then delete them. Providing you with a land-only layer. You then use `Vector > Geoprocessing Tools > Buffer` on the layer with 'land' and create a buffer that will more than fill the gap.
3. Then from the same menu select 'Clip...' And clip the last layer (land) with the first (water; 'Use selected features only').
4. Copy all water features from the original layer (ctrl-c will do) and paste them to the second layer. The second layer will be your end result.

Do not forget to make the layers editable... If you remove the land features from the original layer you may also copy the clipped layers to that one... You may also first create a hull around the original features to clip the end result to. In case any buffered land extends beyond the water.